# Почему не работает try с ресурсами

Tags: java, исключения, while, ресурсы

Не работает try с ресурсами, пытался первую строку добавить, но он пишет на всём предложении `"';' expected"`.

Как ещё можно инициализировать line, чтобы после выполнения while он перестал жить?

```
public class Task implements AutoCloseable{
public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException{
BufferedReader br;
String path = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : null;

try (br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "CP1251")))
{
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (Check(line) == null) {
            continue;
        } else {
            String[] strings = line.split("/");
            Employee emp = new Employee(strings[0], new BigDecimal(strings[1]));
            Department dep = new Department(strings[2]);
            dep.addEmployee(emp);
            System.out.println(strings[0] + " " + strings[1] + " " + strings[2] + " - корректна, обрабатываем");
        }
}
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
            System.out.println("Выбрали корректные варианты");
            System.out.println("---------------------------");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Файл не был найден, проверьте путь");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Исправьте путь к файлу, выходите за массив");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Вы забыли прописать путь к файлу");
        }
}

    public static String[] Check(String line) {
        String regex = "[А-Яа-яЁёA-Za-z\\s]+";
        if (!(line = line.trim()).isEmpty()) {
            String[] strings = line.split("/");
            if (strings.length < 3) {
                System.out.println(line + " - неверный формат строки, ожидаем ФИО/10000.12/Департамент");
                return null;
            }
            if (!(strings[0].matches(regex) && strings[2].matches(regex))) {
                System.out.println(line + " - неверный формат ввода, нужно: Буквы/Цифры/Буквы");
                return null;
            }
            if (!strings[1].matches("\\d{5}(\\.\\d{1,2})?")) {
                System.out.println(line + " - некорректный ввод цифр, знаков. Зарплата не может быть отрицательной и иметь меньше 5 знаков");
                return null;
            }
            return strings;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Читаемый файл закрыт");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BufferedReader необходимо **объявлять** и инициализировать внутри try

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path),"CP1251"))) {}
```

// обновления, с Java 9

```
BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path),"CP1251")); 
try (br) {}
```

Comment: Начиная с Java 9 ресурс можно объявить и инициализировать за пределами блока, а потом просто передать его в try в качестве ресурса

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы. Можно написать и так       
BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path),"CP1251"));                                     
try (br) {}

Answer (score 1):

```
try ( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "CP1251")))
{
    while (true) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        if ( line == null )
            break;

        if (Check(line) == null) {
            continue;
        } else {
            String[] strings = line.split("/");
            Employee emp = new Employee(strings[0], new BigDecimal(strings[1]));
            Department dep = new Department(strings[2]);
            dep.addEmployee(emp);
            System.out.println(strings[0] + " " + strings[1] + " " + strings[2] + " - корректна, обрабатываем");
        }
    }
} // try
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111178/discussion-on-answer-by-alexander-chernin----try--).